# Rails aggregate parent model through scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I would like to create a Rails scope in a model that can allow me to 'select as' the parent model through a scope. For instance:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  scope :include_parent, -> { # code to include parent as 'custom_col_name' }
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many: items
end
```

As a result, I should be able to do something like this:

```
Item.include_parent.first
```

And get:

```
{
  id: 1,
  custom_col_name: {
    id: 2
  }
}
```

I know this can be achieved from the controller doing something similar to:

```
Item.includes(:parent).as_json
```

But I would like to be able to do it from the model instead.

----EDIT----

I have managed to create a scope which includes the parent model attributes by doing this:

```
  scope :include_parent, -> { Item.joins(:parent).select('items.*, parents.* as custom_col_name') }
```

The only remaining issue I have is that the `parent` attributes are not inside the `custom_col_name`, but rather at the same level of the `item` attributes (which causes collisions since both models have an `id`, `created_at`, etc). Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Is there reason why you can't get the instance of Item you want and call parent on that? `parent = Item.first.parent`

Comment: I'm building an RESTful API, the idea is to use this gem: `https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope` + scopes, such that the client can choose to include/or not the parent of the model by using query params as such: GET `items/include_parent=true|false`. With this approach, the server is more agnostic and can support more use-cases for the different types of queries this endpoint might eventually need to handle.